# JMS performance issue or not

Tags: java, performance, jms

My application uses JMS for publishing messages and several subscribe to those topics.

`TopicPublisher` class method is `public void publish(Message message)` used.

but call to `publisher.publish(message);` takes ***2 secs*** on average, checked for ***120 to 200 hits.***

My doubt is :

1. This can be due to network delay??
2. or does JMS calls usually take this much time?

Application Uses **Weblogic 10.3** for JMS communication.

Comment: Check your network bandwidth/latency and message payload size. They might be at fault.

Comment: @AmitG that means, this method would not cause delay??

Comment: Usually publish rate is in thousands of messages per second, so  publish() is definitely anything but slow. check network latency(ping), it is usually the culprit.